# Export Data to xlsx file from UI and compare to find out newly added data

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, export-to-excel

High-level Requirement: I have a web portal which has some data in table grid UI. Daily basis I want to fetch the data and put the data in excel and next day when I am doing the same exercise  then I need to compare the data with previous day and find out the newly added data for current day. Entire thing needs to be done in Java.

I am thinking to proceed with Selenium and pull the data in Arraylist and put it excel and then I'll take the similar file as a input and do the same exercise to find out newly added data.

Expecting suggestions how to proceed. I am a new learner on Apache POI and Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Your overall process sounds like one way you could do what you need to do (I am sure there are others, also). But which step are you stuck on? Using Selenium to access data in a web page? Populating an arraylist with that data? Writing that data to Excel? Performing the data comparison? I would proceed by taking a look at [ask] and also at [mre] for ways to make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: "I need to compare the data with previous day and find out the newly added data for current day.": And your plan is to do this by reading the previous day data from the Excel file? That's not a good idea. Excel is not a good data storage or data exchange format. It is on data  presentation layer. Reading data from Excel files always is laborious and resource consuming. There must be better possibilities to "find out the newly added data for current day". Detecting them out of the data base for example.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: I have managed to deal with selenium. I have now 2 excel files 1 is having Column A, B and another is having A, B, & C. Now, I have to compare both the excels. Let's say Column A in both excel when there is a match some value need to append in adjacent column just like doing vlookup. I know how to read the excel data but how to proceed with comparing and putting the data in adjacent cell that where I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the XLSX file has same structure as target table on a webpage.

My table on web is https://demoqa.com/webtables
and my XLSX file looks like this:
[image]

For table row a pojo object is created and new records are identified if First Name, Last Name and Age is different.

**Code:**

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class SudiptaMajumder extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\myXlsxFile.xlsx");
        List<MyPojo> xlsxPojos = getMyPojosFromXlsxFile(file);
        List<MyPojo> webPojos = getMyPojosFromWeb(driver);
        List<MyPojo> newPojos = filterNewPojos(xlsxPojos, webPojos);
        for (MyPojo pojo: newPojos) {
            System.out.println("new table row detected:");
            System.out.println(pojo.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(pojo.getLastName());
            System.out.println(pojo.getAge());
            System.out.println(pojo.getEmail());
            System.out.println(pojo.getSalary());
            System.out.println(pojo.getDepartment());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static List<MyPojo> getMyPojosFromXlsxFile(File file) throws IOException {
        List<MyPojo> myPojos = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            XSSFCell firstNameCell = row.getCell(0);
            String firstName = firstNameCell.getStringCellValue();
            XSSFCell lastNameCell = row.getCell(1);
            String lastName = lastNameCell.getStringCellValue();
            XSSFCell ageCell = row.getCell(2);
            int age = (int) ageCell.getNumericCellValue();
            XSSFCell emailCell = row.getCell(3);
            String email = emailCell.getStringCellValue();
            XSSFCell salaryCell = row.getCell(4);
            int salary = (int) salaryCell.getNumericCellValue();
            XSSFCell departmentCell = row.getCell(5);
            String department = departmentCell.getStringCellValue();
            myPojos.add(new MyPojo(firstName, lastName, age, email, salary, department));
        }
        workbook.close();
        return myPojos;
    }
    
    public static List<MyPojo> getMyPojosFromWeb(WebDriver driver) {
        List<MyPojo> myPojos = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/webtables");
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("rt-tbody"));
        
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.className("rt-tr-group"));
        for (WebElement row: rows) {
            if (row.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.className("rt-td"));
                String firstName = cells.get(0).getText();
                String lastName = cells.get(1).getText();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(cells.get(2).getText());
                String email = cells.get(3).getText();
                int salary = Integer.parseInt(cells.get(4).getText());
                String department = cells.get(5).getText();
                myPojos.add(new MyPojo(firstName, lastName, age, email, salary, department));
            }
        }
        return myPojos;
    }
    
    public static List<MyPojo> filterNewPojos(List<MyPojo> xlsxPojos, List<MyPojo> webPojos) {
        List<MyPojo> newPojos = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
        for (MyPojo webPojo: webPojos) {
            if (getPojoByNameNadAge(xlsxPojos, webPojo) == null) {
                newPojos.add(webPojo);
            }
        }
        return newPojos;
    }
    
    public static MyPojo getPojoByNameNadAge(List<MyPojo> pojos, MyPojo myPojo) {
        MyPojo filteredPojo = null;
        for (MyPojo pojo: pojos) {
            if (pojo.getFirstName().equals(myPojo.getFirstName()) && pojo.getLastName().equals(myPojo.getLastName()) && pojo.getAge() == myPojo.getAge()) {
                filteredPojo = pojo;
            }
        }
        return filteredPojo;
    }

}

class MyPojo {
    
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String email;
    int salary;
    String department;
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    
    public MyPojo(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String email, int salary, String department) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = department;
    }
    
}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 5922
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Čvc 19, 2022 1:35:21 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
new table row detected:
Kierra
Gentry
29
kierra@example.com
2000
Legal
```